# what if I + what, past tense or present tense?

Tags: grammar

what's the correct tense here:
Is it "the past tense" or "the present tense"?
"What if I miss the bus?"
"What if I were late to dinner?"
"What if I called her tomorrow?"
"What if I don't understand?"

Answer (score 0):

You may use either tense depending on the context or on what you want to convey.

You can even use **will**:

> what if you will go

meaning what if you are willing to go.

Note that I didn’t use “I”: “what if I will go” which is grammatically correct, but illogical, or at least odd since I’m questioning myself if I’m willing to go.

Comment: why did he use the past tense here:What if I called her tomorrow.
Although he talked about future

Comment: It’s the same structure (grammatically second conditional) as “If I called her tomorrow then…”