# When to use ed at the end of the verb

Tags: sentence-construction

Can somebody help me with below sentences.

a) Suppose I changed/change my mind would this change the situation.

b) Suppose I receive/received it on time i would revert you on time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it "If I were you" and not "If I was you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/why-is-it-if-i-were-you-and-not-if-i-was-you)

Comment: I wanted to cite [*what if I + what, **past** tense or **present** tense?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24866/), because that title more exactly matches the question as posed here. But it's got no upvotes or accepted answer, so I can't. It's all the same thing though - *If I **write / wrote / were to write / was to write** this using any of those formats, what difference would it make?*

Comment: In English the subjunctive is more often conjugated in the past tense -- but not exclusively.  Both are possible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Which of the answers to the duplicate question do you think is best, or even correct?  All of them seem to be somewhat off-target.

Comment: @Andrew: I wasn't particularly thinking about the ***answers*** there - just that the framing of the question *(**suppose** + Present / Past)* seemed closer than asking about the ***was / were*** usages (which both look like "Past" anyway).

Comment: I am unable to understand from given links. Plz explain me in simple l. Can we use verb-ed to discribe completed action or it is only use to discribe Past tense.

Comment: @user4084  This is the *subjunctive* tense.  Past/present is not always meaningful when talking about hypothetical situations.

Comment: user4084: Oh, I'm sorry. You can use ***either*** (Present or Past) in your example. When you start a question with ***Suppose... What if... Let's say...*** then what follows *(What if I **gave** an example?)* is a sort of "unreal" situation (neither Present nor Past). Strictly speaking that should involve a ***subjunctive*** verb form *(What if I **were to give** another example?)*, but native speakers often don't bother with that. And it's equally fine for me to say something like *What if I **give** yet another example?).*

Comment: Hands up anyone who thinks those three examples could usefully be included in a new answer to the earlier question I *couldn't* cite as a duplicate. Ideally, would someone else like to actually ***do*** that?